# "Update Shopping Cart" button redirects to homepage when admin setting "Product Redirect to Shopping Cart" is set to No

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

`Magento 2.3.5` Under Nginx

`Update Shopping Cart` button redirects to homepage when pressed. The quantity is updated but the customer is forced to go to the homepage instead of staying in the shopping cart.

In `Store>Configuration>Sales>Checkout>Shopping Cart`, there is a setting called `After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart`. When this is set to `No`, I get this problem of being redirected to the homepage when updating the cart.

When this setting is changed to `Yes`, the problem goes away. `Update Shopping Cart` works normally and the user can update the shopping cart and stays in the cart.

Anyone have some ideas for how to debug this issue?

Comment: I'm also facing a similar issue on Magento 2.4.3-p1. Have you found any solution?